# Guidance and sanity check needed - question on the isomorphism theorems

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

The question is from Joseph .J Rotman's book - Introduction to the Theory of Groups and it goes like this:

 $A,B,C$ are subgroups of $G$, so $A\leq B$, prove that if $(AC=BC\ \text{and}\  A\cap C=B\cap C)$. (we do not assume that either AB or AC is a subgroup) than A=B.

I need you guys to tell me if something is wrong - any criticism is welcomed.
Proof: the map $\varphi:A\rightarrow B/A\cap C $ defined by $\varphi(a)=a(A\cap C)$ is a homomorphism, with $\ker \varphi=A\cap C$

Though it is clrear to me (and maybe it shouldn't be...), I don't know if it is well founded.

Thus by the first isomorphism theorem, $A\cap C \vartriangleleft B$ and $A/A\cap C \cong Im \varphi$

suppose $\varphi$ is not a surjection then there exists $b\in B$ that for all $a\in A$ keeps $b(A\cap C)\neq a(A\cap C)$ and that makes $AC\neq BC$. So our map is a surjection, meaning $A/A\cap C \cong B/A\cap C$. From that I figure that $A\smallsetminus C$ and $B\smallsetminus C$ have the same number of elements, therefore B and A are of the same size. Add that to the fact that $A\leq B$, we  get A=B

QED???

Comment: In the second paragraph, in the definition of $\varphi$, it is not clear why $A\cap B$ should be a normal subgroup of $B$.

Comment: Same thing for $A\cap C$. You definitely can't use the first isomorphism theorem mapping on to a quotient by $A\cap C$ to prove that $A\cap C$ is normal, i.e. that the quotient exists! Is the "no one said..." line Rotman's words or your own? Normally you'd just interpret $AC=BC$ in terms of the generated subgroups.

Comment: The idea of working with cosets points in the right direction. But you cannot use homomorphisms then.  Also, since no finiteness is assumed you cannot argue in terms of cardinality. See my answer below, and sorry for my earlier incorrect statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also do shorter: take any $b\in B$. Since $B\subseteq BC=AC$ there exist $a\in A,c\in C$ such that $b=ac$. Then $a^{-1}b=c$; looking at the left hand side, this is in $B$ (since $A\subseteq B$), looking at the right hand side, this is in $C$, altogether it is in $B\cap C$ and hence in $A\cap C$. In particular, $c\in A$ and therefore  $b=ac\in A$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$B=\bigcup_{b\in B}b(B\cap C)$$
and 
$$A=\bigcup_{a\in A}a(A\cap C).$$
Now, for $b,b'\in B$ we have $b(B\cap C)=b'(B\cap C)$ if and only if $b^{-1}b'\in B\cap C$ if an only if $b^{-1}b'\in C$ since $b^{-1}b'\in B$ is automatically true. From $B\subseteq BC$ and the assumption that $BC=AC$ it follows that for every $b\in B$ there exist $a\in A,c\in C$ such that $b=ac$. But then $a^{-1}b=c\in C\cap B$ (since $a^{-1}\in B$ by $A\subseteq B$) and it follows that $b(B\cap C)=a(B\cap C)=a(A\cap C)$. Altogether:
$$\forall b\in B\ \exists a\in A: b(B\cap C)=a(A\cap C).$$

It follows that that the two unions of cosets are the same and $A=B$.

Comment: no... it's 2.48, 4th edition. it does not say that they are normal

Comment: can you prove it wrong?